# WPF - Appending string content in grid cell

Tags: wpf, grid, alignment

I have a tooltip which contains a 2X2 grid (see code below). The value in row 1 col 1 is dynamically assigned, but I want to append it to the string in the cell to the left.

Example: The user should see:

Default: 0.5, Min: 0, Max: 1092, Current: 2

But right now it reads:

Default: 0.5, Min: 0, Max: 1092, Current: (multiple spaces here) 2

Seems like it should be simple, but I can't quite get it to work. Alternatively, I would like to at least align this value to the left side of the cell as it currently appears to be in the center, but HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition />
<ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition />
<RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Time after removing all keycards that the relay will switch states</Label>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >Default: 0.5, Min: 0, Max: 1092, Current:</Label>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="1">
<Label.Content>
<Binding Path="EgressTimeout"
Converter="{StaticResource timeConverter}" />
</Label.Content>
</Label>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is because without defining your grid and/or column widths, it makes them the same size and takes all of the available space in the container.  The "multiple spaces" you're seeing is the remaining width of the first column, which is 50% the width of entire container the way it is written.  Add the ShowGridLines="true" property to see what I mean.

To get rid of the extra space, you could set the first column width to Auto or some other defined width.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="yourOriginalGrid" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Time after removing all keycards that the relay will switch states</Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >Default: 0.5, Min: 0, Max: 1092, Current:</Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="1">1492</Label>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Azure" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Time after removing all keycards that the relay will switch states</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >Default: 0.5, Min: 0, Max: 1092, Current:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="1" Margin="2 0">1492</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will play around with it and see how it works. Seeing the gridlines will be very helpful.